# Efficient ways to check whether a matrix is zero-matrix in Julia

Tags: arrays, julia

I have an n-by-n matrix (n-very large) that I want to check whether it is a zero matrix or not in Julia. One of the ways that I tried is the following

```
using BenchmarkTools
using Random

A = rand(2000,2000); # n = 2000 for instance.
@btime all($A .== 0)
```

which outputs to

```
2.380 ms (4 allocations: 492.59 KiB)
false
```

Is there any other efficient ways to achieve the same?

Comment: If the matrix is sparse (in the standard CSC format), checking is even faster. Depending on criticality and usage, maintaining a filled element count alongside matrix might be the way to go.

Answer (score 5):

There is a dedicated function for finding out whether an object is an 'additive identity', i.e. zero. And this function works also for arrays:

```
iszero(A)
```

Internally, this is implemented as `all(iszero, A)`, but I prefer just `iszero(A)` since it is more generic.

In some cases, such as for sparse arrays, `iszero(A)` can be much faster than `all(iszero, A)`, since the latter will iterate over every element, while `iszero(A)` only iterates over the structurally non-zero elements.

Answer (score 3):

Broadcasting `==` first allocates a new boolean array, which you don't really need.  For cases like this, `all` has a method accepting a predicate as the first argument:

```
julia> @btime all($A .== 0)
  3.744 ms (4 allocations: 492.59 KiB)
false

julia> @btime all(iszero, $A)
  2.880 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
false
```

This has the additional advantage of short-circuiting, i.e., stopping after the first `false`.